# How get seed phrase similar seed phrase from phantom?

Tags: python

i exported wallet data from phantom wallet:

```
seed phrase: warfare heavy proof ecology water grit toddler blade venue right denial rival
public key: DudBEyhvkAtgTWoaXSUgV2Zv7V1GgsfYGZvs9P8xztff
private key: 435uZmJmyAUzPCj8Jwmdbv7xfiKS6KkUxtwMDdfyxAycRbm9zB2Cx5gineoSkxabdWV5S2TEU2PawngsdnPuxGF7
```

Next I am trying to get the same public key and recovery phrase from the private key using python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import base58
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from mnemonic import Mnemonic

mnemo = Mnemonic("english")

private_key ='435uZmJmyAUzPCj8Jwmdbv7xfiKS6KkUxtwMDdfyxAycRbm9zB2Cx5gineoSkxabdWV5S2TEU2PawngsdnPuxGF7'
keypair=Keypair.from_base58_string(private_key)
seed_phrase = mnemo.to_mnemonic(keypair.secret())
print(keypair.pubkey())
print(seed_phrase)
------
DudBEyhvkAtgTWoaXSUgV2Zv7V1GgsfYGZvs9P8xztff
oak skate multiply system put social royal three consider crowd maple dentist manual tag private fiction bench slim above tourist scrap damage bind jewel
```

The recovery phrase does not match both in terms of the number of words and the words themselves.
Why is this happening and is it possible to generate a similar phrase?

As far as I understand the problem is that phantom uses the B44 algorithm, while solana-py uses B39 (the solana standard). How to solve this problem?

Comment: That is probably the private key for a wallet derived from the recovery phrase. Not some sort of private key for the recovery phrase